# jQuery UI Accordion + Cookies - Closed by Default?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

With the jQuery UI Accordion, I am successful in the use of cookies to remember the last active state when refreshing the page- however I am unable to:

1. set to collapsed on first visit
2. have cookie remember if the user has manually collapsed after opening

I've tried to attempt creating a function with conditional statement on the "active" option but was unsuccessful.

http://jsfiddle.net/77xC9/18/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        var act = 0;
        $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
            create: function(event, ui) {
                //get index in cookie on accordion create event
                if($.cookie('saved_index') != null){
                   act =  parseInt($.cookie('saved_index'));
                }
            },
            change: function(event, ui) {
                //set cookie for current index on change event
                $.cookie('saved_index', null);
                $.cookie('saved_index', ui.options.active);
            },
            active:parseInt($.cookie('saved_index')),
            collapsible: true
        });
    });
```

​

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
        change: function(event, ui) {
            $.cookie('saved_index', ui.options.active !== false ? ui.options.active : null);
        },
        active: $.cookie('saved_index') != null ? parseInt($.cookie('saved_index')) : false,
        collapsible: true
    });
});
```

ps: Google Chrome does not accept cookies if you open your page as a local file.

Comment: This solves issue #1 (showing as collapsed on first visit).  However I still can't seem to get it to remember if the user has collapsed the menu.  (make sure all menus are closed, and hit refresh).  

http://jsfiddle.net/77xC9/25/

Answer (score 11):

The shared code doesn't work in jQuery UI 1.9+. Following code works!

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $("#accordion").accordion({
        activate: function(event, ui) {
            $.cookie('saved_index', $("#accordion").accordion("option", "active"));
        },
        active: parseInt($.cookie('saved_index')),
        collapsible: true
    });
});
```

Comment: Why do you need a `$.cookie('saved_index', null);` line?

Comment: @FilipSpiridonov Indeed, that line is not needed and it works fine without.