# how to make the selected menu stay selected jquery, css , html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

accordian menu , has to make the submenu to stay selected after clicking by js. or css .

not the static solution in html. 
need solution comprising jquery and the css
it should appear same as hovering after clicked

check out the fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/shaswatatripathy/ucgff65k/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#accordion > li > div").click(function() {
    $("#submenu li").slideUp();
    if (!$(this).next().is(":visible")) {
      $(this).next().slideDown();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.accordion {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 260px;
  background: #FFF;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.accordion .link {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 15px 15px 42px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 700;
  border-top: 1px solid #CCC;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
  border-right: 1px solid #CCC;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}


/*-------------Submenu-----------------------------*/

.submenu {
  padding: 0px;
  display: none;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.submenu li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #4b4a5e;
}

.submenu a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #23222d;
  background-color: #CCC;
  padding: 12px;
  padding-left: 42px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.25s ease;
  transition: all 0.25s ease;
}

#submenu li.active {
  display: block;
}

.submenu a:hover {
  background: #b63b4d;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="accordion" class="accordion">
  <li>
    <div class="link">Menu 2</div>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="#">submenu1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">submenu1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">submenu1</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="link">Menu 3</div>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="#">submenu1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">submenu1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">submenu1</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11231436/jquery-ui-accordion-menu-saving-menu-state-even-after-refresh

Comment: cant use cookie or local storage. just wanted to make the clicked submenu to stay selected till anything clicked. how its appearing when hovering , it should appear after clicked .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this is what you're looking for,

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#accordion > li > div").click(function() {
    $("#submenu li").slideUp();
    if (!$(this).next().is(":visible")) {
      $(this).next().slideDown();
    }
  });
  
  $(".submenu li a").click(function(){
    $(".submenu li a.active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
  });
});
```

```css
.accordion {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 260px;
  background: #FFF;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.accordion .link {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 15px 15px 42px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 700;
  border-top: 1px solid #CCC;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
  border-right: 1px solid #CCC;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}


/*-------------Submenu-----------------------------*/

.submenu {
  padding: 0px;
  display: none;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.submenu li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #4b4a5e;
}

.submenu a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #23222d;
  background-color: #CCC;
  padding: 12px;
  padding-left: 42px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.25s ease;
  transition: all 0.25s ease;
}

#submenu li.active {
  display: block;
}

.submenu a:hover {
  background: #b63b4d;
  color: #FFF;
}
.submenu li a.active {
  background: #b63b4d;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="accordion" class="accordion">
  <li>
    <div class="link">Menu 2</div>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="#">submenu1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">submenu1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">submenu1</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="link">Menu 3</div>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="#">submenu1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">submenu1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">submenu1</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an `.active` class for the `<a>` tag inside `<li>` which matches the CSS of the `:hover` state of `<a>`, like this:

```
a.active {
  background: #b63b4d;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

And then just use the click event listener to add and remove this class when clicked on the submenu:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

   $("#accordion > li > div").click(function() {
     if (!$(this).next().is(":visible")) {
       $(this).next().slideDown();
     } else {
       $(this).next().slideUp();
     }
   });

   $(".submenu a").click(function() {
            $(this).toggleClass("active").parent().siblings().find("a").removeClass("active");
   });

 });
```

I also modified to jQuery so that the accordion closes when it is clicked on in the open state.

Here's the working jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ucgff65k/2/
And the code snippet:

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
 
   $("#accordion > li > div").click(function() {
     if (!$(this).next().is(":visible")) {
       $(this).next().slideDown();
     } else {
       $(this).next().slideUp();
     }
   });
   
   $(".submenu a").click(function() {
       $(this).toggleClass("active").parent().siblings().find("a").removeClass("active");
   });
   
 });
```

```css
.accordion {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 260px;
  background: #FFF;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.accordion .link {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 15px 15px 42px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 700;
  border-top: 1px solid #CCC;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
  border-right: 1px solid #CCC;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}


/*-------------Submenu-----------------------------*/

.submenu {
  padding: 0px;
  display: none;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.submenu li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #4b4a5e;
}

.submenu a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #23222d;
  background-color: #CCC;
  padding: 12px;
  padding-left: 42px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.25s ease;
  transition: all 0.25s ease;
}

.submenu a:hover {
  background: #b63b4d;
  color: #FFF;
}

a.active {
  background: #b63b4d;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="accordion" class="accordion">
  <li>
    <div class="link">Menu 2</div>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="#">submenu1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">submenu1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">submenu1</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="link">Menu 3</div>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="#">submenu1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">submenu1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">submenu1</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```